# Token Google API C# .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-sheets, .net-core

I am making a auto fill program for google spreedsheet(using MVC without the VIEW) when callign the function in the browser.

I made the service that runs perfectly in my local machine (but the token is retrieved by GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker, the browser shows, logins automatically and close, without the user needs to click anything) and can stay running forever until i stop the service...

when i publish and deploy in IIS, it doesnt work nothing... with a little of research i found that GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker cant be used in IIS due to obligation of navigator... i tried hard (unsuccessfully) to use GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow or get the token via post...

I am using .net core 2.1

CONTROLLER.CS

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Cargas.Data.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace SrvAppCargaGoogleSheet.Controllers
{    
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class CargaGoogleSheetController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        #region CONSTRUTOR
        private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        private readonly CargaGoogleSheetRepository _CargaGoogleSheetRepo;


        public CargaGoogleSheetController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            _CargaGoogleSheetRepo = new CargaGoogleSheetRepository(Configuration,hostingEnvironment);
        }
        #endregion

        [HttpGet]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public IActionResult Operacional()
        {
            try
            {

                while (1 > 0)
                {

                    var test_con = _CargaGoogleSheetRepo.CheckForInternetConnection();


                    while (test_con == false)
                    {
                        test_con = _CargaGoogleSheetRepo.CheckForInternetConnection();
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    }
                    
                    _CargaGoogleSheetRepo.atualizarOperacional();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message + " " + (e.InnerException == null ? "" : e.InnerException.Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

REPOSITORY.CS

```
using Cargas.Data.Models;
using Cargas.Data.Models.Logistica;
using Cargas.Data.Models.Operacional;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Cargas.Data.Repositories
{
    public class CargaGoogleSheetRepository
    {
        #region CONSTRUTOR;
        private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        private string _scDBPad = "";
        private string _scDBMysql = "";
        private string _scDBSigpatSql = "";
        private string _scDBProdOp = "";
        private string _dbMySqlContrefetivo = "";
        private string _dbContrefetivo = "";
        private string _dbFolha_11_Medalha = "";
        private string _dbAssunto_NBI = "";
        private string _dbAlmanaqueSgt = "";
        private string _dbAlmanaqueOficiais = "";
        private string _dbAfastDsDr = "";
        private string _dbVWMaterialSql = "";
        private string _dbVWQCMSql = "";
        private string _dbSituacaoMaterialSql = "";
        private string _dbMarcaSql = "";
        private string _dbDetentorSql = "";
        private string _dbPTR = "";
        private string _dbPTRBI = "";
        private string _dbPTRCPNBI = "";



        IConfiguration Configuration;
        public CargaGoogleSheetRepository(IConfiguration Configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
            this.Configuration = Configuration;
            _scDBPad = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnPadrao");
            _scDBMysql = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnMySql");
            _scDBSigpatSql = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnSIGPATSql");
            _scDBProdOp = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnProdOp");
            _dbMySqlContrefetivo = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MySqlContrefetivo");
            _dbContrefetivo = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Contrefetivo");
            _dbFolha_11_Medalha = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Folha_11_Medalha");
            _dbAssunto_NBI = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Assunto_NBI");
            _dbAlmanaqueSgt = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AlmanaqueSgt");
            _dbAlmanaqueOficiais = Configuration.GetValue<string>("AlmanaqueOficiais");
            _dbAfastDsDr = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Folha_3");
            _dbVWMaterialSql = Configuration.GetValue<string>("VWMaterialSql");
            _dbVWQCMSql = Configuration.GetValue<string>("VWQCMSql");
            _dbSituacaoMaterialSql = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SituacaoMaterialSql");
            _dbMarcaSql = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MarcaSql");
            _dbDetentorSql = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DetentorSql");
            _dbPTR = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PTR");
            _dbPTRBI = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PTRBI");
            _dbPTRCPNBI = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PTRCPNBI");


        }
        #endregion

public bool CheckForInternetConnection()
        {
            try
            {

                Ping myPing = new Ping();
                String host = "google.com";
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
                int timeout = 1000;
                PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
                PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (reply.Status == IPStatus.TimedOut)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


        //API GOOGLE

        static readonly string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
        static readonly string ApplicationName = "***************";
        static readonly string SpreadsheetIdPessoas = "**************";
        static readonly string SpreadsheetIdLogistica = "****************";
        static readonly string SpreadsheetIdOperacional = "**************";
        //Planilhas Pessoas
        static readonly string EfeSheet = "Efetivo Atual";
        static readonly string LaureaSheet = "Laureas";
        static readonly string AlmaSgtSheet = "Almanaque Sgt";
        static readonly string AlmaOfSheet = "Almanaque Of";
        static readonly string AfastDsDrSheet = "Afastamentos DS e DR";
        //Planilhas Logística
        static readonly string MatSheet = "Materiais";
        static readonly string DetPorCodSheet = "Det Por Cod";
        //Planilha Operacional
        static readonly string USAtivaSheet = "US Ativa";
        static readonly string CompVtrSheet = "Comp Viaturas";
        static SheetsService service;

        //private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();



        public void loginGoogle()
        {

            
            UserCredential credential;
   

        string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
            using (
                var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                 //The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
               // Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
        }
```

STARTUP.CS

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SrvAppCargaGoogleSheet
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                  builder =>
                  {
                      builder.WithOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:4200",
                        "http://localhost:4201",
                        "http://localhost:4300",
                        "***************",
                        "***************",
                        "*************",
                        "****************************",
                        "****************************",
                        "****************************",
                        "****************", //HML DMZ Angular
                        "****************", //HML DMZ .Net
                        "****************", //PRD DMZ .Net
                        "****************",
                        "*")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
                  });
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "APICARGAGOOGLESHEET", Version = "v1" });
                c.CustomSchemaIds(i => i.FullName);
            });

            services.AddMemoryCache();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Definindo a cultura padrão: pt-BR
            var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Request.EnableRewind();
                await next();
            });

            app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());

            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
            });


            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "APICARGAGOOGLESHEET");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Program.CS

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;


namespace SrvAppCargaGoogleSheet
{

    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }
        
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

CREDENTIALS.json

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "******************",
    "project_id": "**************",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "*****************",
    "redirect_uris": [ "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: An application doesn't have access to the file system on a IIS.  Any connection to the server is set to GUEST privilege's and have very limited access to the IIS machine.  Any files needed by an application should be placed on a network drive  with more access. You do not want to give apps more privilege's to allow hackers a back door to the machine.  In your code you have following :  new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))

Comment: Don't put your Google search in the title of your questions.  Put a summary of your problem in the question title instead.

Comment: @jdweng I set IIS User to have admin privileges in the folder properties, the server is restricted to intranet requests.
i made a change and now i am using the .p12 certificate and its working on my machine(no need to user consent), didnt test on IIS... but the application will have to use the certificate.p12 inside the folder, can it be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

[GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker cannot be used server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71173193/token-google-api-c-sharp-net-core-2-1), as you already discovered.

Here's [documentation and sample code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3) for how to do server side end user OAuth for ASP.NET Core 3.

If you cannot possibly move to ASP.NET Core 3, then here is [sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/main/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore.IntegrationTests) for ASP.NET Core 2.

This is what your `ConfigureServices` in Startup.cs should look like - they're the same for both ASP.NET Core 2 and ASP.NET Core 3:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            // This is for challenges to go directly to the Google OpenID Handler,
            // so there's no need to add an AccountController that emits challenges
            // for Login.
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // This forbids going directly to the Google OpenID Handler,
            // which checks if extra scopes are required and does automatic
            // incremental auth.
            o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "your-client-id";
            options.ClientSecret = "your-client-secret";
        });
    // Everything else your app needs like:
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

And then in the controller, you can obtain the credential as follows:

```cs
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> UseGoogleSheets(
    [FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    // Use the credential to create the SheetsService etc.
    // as you are already doing in your code.
}
```

Again, these are just the basic snippets, take a look at the full documentation and the sample code to find out about other supported features like incremental auth, etc.

Also, feel free to follow up on this thread, or create issues in https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client.

Comment: I swapped googlewebauthorization for serviceaccount (using the old .p12 certificate)... made this before seeing your reply... in my local machine, worked perfectly(no need of user consent) now i need to test in IIS Server, if fails, i will try ConfigureServices....
thanks!